# Drupal's global language returns wrong language

Tags: php, drupal, translation, drupal-modules

I have a site with few translations, Everything works fine, but the last language I've add.
Languages, are separated by the domains, and the new one (za) returns (en) via Global $language instead.

Here is the screenshot with the language list.

[image: Here]

How could it be? Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Drupal cache in Configuration->Performance?

Comment: sure, nothig changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, i've used http instead of https in lang domain on the config page. Be carefull.